# How can I fix my dropdown menu to be fixed position with scrolling in adobe XD?

Tags: adobe-xd

I am trying to design a website with adobe xd. One of the common feature of any website is to have dropdown menu. In my design I am prototyping the dropdown menu list to another artboard. My problem arises when i scroll the artboard, my dropdown list goes to another viewport. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, while previewing your art board, you want the drop down menu to hold its position in the window. To do so, go into prototype mode, click the drop down menu, and in the panel on the right side you will see a selection for fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Prototype mode.
Select the element in your Artboard. (Here, the Drop-down menu)
Now make sure, "Fix Position When Scrolling" is checked, in the Interaction's option panel.


[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing i saw in the recent update was to move the item to the top in the layer stack, once you move the group/component/item to the top of the stack then you'll see "Fix Position when Scrolling option". In the image below i wanted header to be fixed so i moved it up in the stack and it showed me the option.

[image]